# getting Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory on sass watch command

Tags: ruby, sass

I installed Ruby on my Windows system to use `Sass` in order to follow Best practices in CSS Theming in my PHP project, as given in [Best Practices - CSS Theming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662351/best-practices-css-theming). I have never used Ruby or Sass before.

After installation, I went to `Start Command Prompt with Ruby` and entered -

```
gem install sass
```

and it installed successfully.

Then following the tutorial given in http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html,

I created two files `test.scss` and `test.css` at `/some/path` which is inside my web directory (PHP development environment). I wrote the following in `test.scss` -

```
/* test.scss */
#navbar {
  width: 80%;
  height: 23px;
}
```

I cd'ed to the `/some/path` in the Ruby Command prompt and entered -

```
sass --watch test.scss:test.css
```

And got this output -

```
Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - test.scss
Use --trace for backtrace
```

The errors comes even if I give the entire absolute path of the css files. If I add --trace to the command, following is the output -

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:317:i
n `read': No such file or directory - C:\xampp\htdocs\examvillage_recovered\bran
ches\I18N\trunk\style\dev_styles\test.scss (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/comp
iler.rb:317:in `update_stylesheet'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/comp
iler.rb:169:in `block in update_stylesheets'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/comp
iler.rb:167:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/comp
iler.rb:167:in `update_stylesheets'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/comp
iler.rb:214:in `watch'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin.rb:1
11:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/exec.rb:408
:in `watch_or_update'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/exec.rb:294
:in `process_result'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/exec.rb:41:
in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/exec.rb:21:
in `parse!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.1/bin/sass:8:in `<top
(required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/sass:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/sass:19:in `<main>'
```

Then went through this youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_-HLevIJbc where the installation steps are mention. I installed gem `haml` too and it installed successfully.

But I am still getting this error with an extra notice

```
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement.
It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
1/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.0.gemspec:11.
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - C:\xampp\htdocs\examvillage_recovere
\branches\I18N\trunk\style\dev_styles\test.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

How do I fix this? Any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you open cmd. Then give the full path to the parent folder of the folder where your scss file is located. Then type "sass --watch Foldername:Foldername" then press enter.

In your case it should look something similar to this in the cmd:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\examvillage_recovered\branches\I18N\trunk\style>sass --watch dev_styles:dev_styles
```